# Recursively create a new Data Frame using for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a below code which i wrote It creates a new data frame for different SerialNumber character length and at the end I append all the dataframe together to get the final Output.

I am trying to find a better way writing this code. Can I do this using a for loop ?

```
data["Serial Number"] = data['Serial Number'].str.zfill(28)
print ("Fetch Serial Number with 28 characters")
data["Output"] = data['Serial Number'].apply(lambda x: fetch_by_ser_no(x))
data.to_excel(r'first.xlsx',index = False)
data.loc[:,"itemlen"] = data["Output"].str.len()
data.loc[:,"SNlen"] = data["Serial Number"].str.len()
df = data.loc[(data['itemlen']== 1)& (data['SNlen'] == 28)]
data.drop(data[(data['SNlen'] == 28  ) & (data['itemlen'] == 1) ].index,inplace = True)
df.to_excel(r'raw.xlsx',index = False)


data["Serial Number"] = data['Serial Number'].str.zfill(30)
print ("Fetch Serial Number with 30 characters")
data["Output"] = data['Serial Number'].apply(lambda x: fetch_by_ser_no(x))
data.loc[:,"itemlen"] = data["Output"].str.len()
data.loc[:,"SNlen"] = data["Serial Number"].str.len()
df1= data.loc[(data['itemlen']== 1)& (data['SNlen'] == 30)]
data.drop(data[(data['SNlen'] == 30  ) & (data['itemlen'] == 1) ].index,inplace = True)
df1.to_excel(r'raw1.xlsx',index = False)


data["Serial Number"] = data['Serial Number'].str.zfill(32)
print ("Fetch Serial Number with 32 characters")
data["Output"] = data['Serial Number'].apply(lambda x: fetch_by_ser_no(x))
data.loc[:,"itemlen"] = data["Output"].str.len()
data.loc[:,"SNlen"] = data["Serial Number"].str.len()
df2= data.loc[(data['itemlen']== 1)& (data['SNlen'] == 32)]
data.drop(data[(data['SNlen'] == 32  ) & (data['itemlen'] == 1) ].index,inplace = True)
df2.to_excel(r'raw2.xlsx',index = False)

data["Serial Number"] = data['Serial Number'].str.zfill(34)
print ("Fetch Serial Number with 34 characters")
data["Output"] = data['Serial Number'].apply(lambda x: fetch_by_ser_no(x))
data.loc[:,"itemlen"] = data["Output"].str.len()
data.loc[:,"SNlen"] = data["Serial Number"].str.len()
data = data.append([df,df1,df2])
```

Comment: Yes ..I but was debating between function or for loop? What would be the best way to do it ?I want do this for Serial Number character length 28,30,32,&34.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOOP

```
data = {}
i = 28
data1 = []
while i <= 34:
    data["Serial Number"] = data['Serial Number'].str.zfill(i)
    print("Fetch Serial Number with" + i + "characters")
    data["Output"] = data['Serial Number'].apply(lambda x: fetch_by_ser_no(x))
    data.to_excel(r'first.xlsx',index = False)
    data.loc[:,"itemlen"] = data["Output"].str.len()
    data.loc[:,"SNlen"] = data["Serial Number"].str.len()
    df = data.loc[(data['itemlen']== 1)& (data['SNlen'] == i)]
    data.drop(data[(data['SNlen'] == i  ) & (data['itemlen'] == 1) ].index,inplace = True)
    data1.append(df)
    i = i + 2
```

Comment: How can I print the data frame to excel?

Comment: `data1[n]` is each of your dataframes. To print the first, `data1[0].to_excel(r'raw1.xlsx',index = False)`

Comment: I don't want to drop the rows in the last iteration. If you see my code the last loop for 34 is little different. When I run the code for Serial Number with 34 characters I keep data with itemlen = 0 & 1

Comment: Oh i see. Add a `if i != 24:` statement and you should be good